# How to setup scan to email (without computer) for Brother Printer MFC 7860 DW

Tags: email, gmail, smtp, brother-printer

I have [Brother Printer MFC 7860 DW](https://coderwall.com/p/u9hlzw/getting-scan-to-email-working-with-the-brother-mfc7860dw) and I want to scan documents from its scanner and [send the scan directly to given email address](http://www.printerbase.co.uk/news/brother-enable-scan-direct-to-email-server/), without using the computer again after setting up everything.

[I have upgraded the latest Firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igdqt.jpg). I'm on OSX.

I have these options but I don't know how to configure them. I just want get scans on an email. Can anyone help me what to fill here to get Scans on my personal gmail address?

[image]

I found this while searching in google but either this solution not working for me or I'm unable to understand it https://coderwall.com/p/u9hlzw/getting-scan-to-email-working-with-the-brother-mfc7860dw

Comment: It is all explained in the [Network User Guide](https://www.brother-usa.com/ModelDocuments/Consumer/Network%20Users%20Manual/NUM_DCP_7065DN_HL_2280DW_MFC_7360N_7460DN_7860DW_EN_2845.PDF)

Comment: @DavidPostill I have tried it but either I'm not able to understand or it's not working either. I'm trying to do this from last 1 year, not able to crack it yet

Comment: Also in network user guide there is no proper instruction to setup "Scan to Email"

Comment: Yes there is. See section 8, p66/67 "Sending an Email Securly"

Comment: [Get started with IMAP and POP3](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665119,1665162)

Comment: I am trying to make my MFC L8850 printer works with gmail too. I've tried various settings to no avail. I was able to get 1 notification of a blocked connexion once, not sure what settings were used, but seems it might required to activate the "less secure app" setting in the google account security, which is not mentionned in the brother's network manual, DavidPostill.